# Why are the extra codecs causing errors for the Media Source API?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, codec, media-source, mp4box

I used mp4box(https://gpac.github.io/mp4box.js/dist/mp4box.all.js) to generate
`video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2, avc1.42e01e, rtp , rtp "`. When `MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)`  is run it shows false. I know this mimeCodec works: `video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"` Why does the Media Source API not accept what mp4box gathered and is there a way to make mp4box(or a similar program) provide `video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"` automatically. I got the video from here: https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/main/sourcebuffer/frag_bunny.mp4. The following code is what I used to make `video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2, avc1.42e01e, rtp , rtp "`

```
const assetURL = "frag_bunny.mp4";

mimeCodec=""

const mp4boxfile = MP4Box.createFile();
mp4boxfile.onError = console.error;
mp4boxfile.onReady = (info) => {
  console.log( info.tracks.map( track => track.codec ) );
  arraymimeCodec=info.tracks.map( track => track.codec )
  RepNum=0
  while(arraymimeCodec[RepNum]){
    mimeCodec=mimeCodec+arraymimeCodec[RepNum]
    RepNum++
    if(arraymimeCodec[RepNum]){mimeCodec=mimeCodec+", "}
  }
mimeCodec='video/mp4; codecs="'+mimeCodec+'"'
};

fetch(assetURL).then( (resp) => resp.arrayBuffer() )
  .then( (buf) => {
    buf.fileStart = 0;
    mp4boxfile.appendBuffer( buf );
    mp4boxfile.flush();
  } );
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your MIME type shouldn't include the types of the `metadata` tracks. Simply filter those out when you generate your mime type, or even, select only the first video and audio tracks:

```js
const assetURL = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdn/dom-examples/sourcebuffer/frag_bunny.mp4";

const mp4boxfile = MP4Box.createFile();
mp4boxfile.onError = console.error;
mp4boxfile.onReady = ({ tracks }) => {
  const videoCodec = tracks.find(({ type }) => type === "video")?.codec;
  const audioCodec = tracks.find(({ type }) => type === "audio")?.codec;
  const codecs = [videoCodec, audioCodec].filter(Boolean).join(", ");
  const mimeCodec = `video/mp4; codecs="${codecs}"`;
  console.log(mimeCodec, "- supported:", MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec));
  // To show that there are metadata tracks in this file:
  console.log(tracks.map(({type}) => type));
}

fetch(assetURL).then((resp) => resp.arrayBuffer())
  .then((buf) => {
    buf.fileStart = 0;
    mp4boxfile.appendBuffer(buf);
    mp4boxfile.flush();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://gpac.github.io/mp4box.js/dist/mp4box.all.js"></script>
```